# QMessage::question(),,the dialog should be modal but it's not somtimes,the dialog was showed under the MainWindow

Tags: c++, qt

//QMessageBox dialog is modal by default,but the dialog was showed under the mainwindow

```
int res = QMessageBox::question(NULL, tr("Question"), tr("Are you sure to delete this rules?"), 
QMessageBox::Yes | QMessageBox::Cancel);
if (QMessageBox::Yes == res)
{
    QStringList result;
    for (int i = selectedrowset.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        //record data
        QTableWidgetItem* item = this->item(selectedrowset.at(i), 0);
        if (item)
        {
            QString text = item->text();
            if (!result.contains(text))
                result.append(text);
        }
        this->removeRow(selectedrowset.at(i));
    }
    emit signal_delete(result);
}
```

Comment: You used `NULL` as `parent` (widget) in [QMessageBox::question()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmessagebox.html#question). Instead, you may set the pointer to widget from which this dialog is opened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A QDialog is modal to its parent(s), but are giving *no parent at all*, since you're using *`NULL`*.

As shown in the [documentation examples](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmessagebox.html#the-static-functions-api):

```
int ret = QMessageBox::warning(this, tr("My Application"),
                               tr("The document has been modified.\n"
                                  "Do you want to save your changes?"),
                               QMessageBox::Save | QMessageBox::Discard
                               | QMessageBox::Cancel,
                               QMessageBox::Save);
```

Add the main window as a parent (the first argument), and the messagebox will be modal to it.

Comment: my this is a QTableWidget ,is it ok  ?

Comment: It doesn't matter, it just has to be a QWidget, Qt will automatically use that widget's top level window as a reference.